# Meaning of もクソも in 何かもクソも寝るだけだよ

Tags: meaning, translation

I know that ～もくそも（ない) is is an expression that can mean:  not at all; not even a little​

However I'm still confused at what もクソも in 何かもクソも寝るだけだよ means.[image]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ～もクソも(ない) is a dirty version of ～も何も(ない) described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64794/5010) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62545/5010). In slangy speech, 何 in ～も何も can be replaced by クソ, ヘチマ, へったくれ, etc., which are basically metaphors for crappy/meaningless things (see [this discussion](https://www.ytv.co.jp/michiura/time/2011/06/post-768.html) in Japanese). In this context, he is saying asking "何(か)" to him is meaningless.

> 何してるの?
> What are you doing?
>
> 何かもクソも、寝るだけだよ。
> = 何かもクソもないよ、寝るだけだよ。
> = 何かも何も(ないよ)、寝るだけだよ。
> Why d'you ask? I'm just about to go to bed.

Comment: Would "neither something nor nothing" be a reasonable translation? That's something we certainly might say in English if we were telling someone to mind their own business, or that their question was stupid.

Comment: @user3856370 Um, sorry, I do not know that idiom... But yes, he is saying he was asked a stupid question.

Comment: @user3856370 I've never heard this idiom either.

Comment: @AeonAkechi Never mind then. Maybe it's a UK thing. Maybe it's a regional UK thing. Maybe it's just my personal understanding. The interweb has nothing to say about it.

Comment: @user3856370 Well, if it's regional, that region certainly isn't Yorkshire (where I'm from).

Comment: @AeonAkechi Bizarrely, I'm from Yorkshire. Maybe I should translate to: "It's neither owt n' nowt".

Comment: @user3856370 Ohh, that does sound somewhat familiar now that you put it like that.

Comment: `It's neither owt n' nowt` ? わからんｗｗ